# Kalman for 3D position and 1D orientation

Tags: computer-vision, kalman-filters, control-systems, adaptive-filters

Is the following state correct for a Constant Acceleration (CA) model KF applied for tracking an object which moves in (x, y, z) and have the freedom of rotation $\phi$ around the $z$ axis?

\begin{equation}
 x= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 x, \dot x, \ddot x, y, \dot y, \ddot y, z, \dot z, \ddot z, \phi, \dot \phi, \ddot \phi
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

---

UPDATE:

I can only measure $(x, y, z)$, directly. After, I computed $\phi$, rotation around the $z$ axis, using $\arctan(\frac{\delta y}{\delta x})$, indirectly. The measurements that I input to KF are: $x, y, z, \phi$.

Assuming:
\begin{equation}
\pmb{\alpha}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & dt & 0.5 \times dt^2 \\
0  & 1  & dt \\
0  & 0  & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{3 \times 3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\pmb{\beta}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}_{1 \times 3}
\end{equation}

$A$, the state transition matrix which applies the effect of each state parameter at time $t-1$ on the state at time $t$, is built using:
\begin{equation}
x_{k+1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\pmb{\alpha}_{3 \times 3}  & 0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} \\
0_{3 \times 3}  & \pmb{\alpha}_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} \\
0_{3 \times 3}  & 0_{3 \times 3} & \pmb{\alpha}_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} \\
0_{3 \times 3}  & 0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} & \pmb{\alpha}_{3 \times 3} \\
\end{bmatrix}_{12 \times 12}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ \dot x\\ \ddot x\\ y\\ \dot y\\ \ddot y\\ z\\ \dot z\\ \ddot z\\ \phi\\ \dot \phi\\ \ddot \phi
\end{bmatrix}_{k}
\end{equation}

In the same manner, the transformation matrix $H$, which map state vector parameters into the measurements domain, is built using:
\begin{equation}
H=
\begin{bmatrix}
\pmb{\beta}_{1 \times 3}  & 0_{1 \times 3} & 0_{1 \times 3} & 0_{1 \times 3} \\
0_{1 \times 3}  & \pmb{\beta}_{1 \times 3} & 0_{1 \times 3} & 0_{1 \times 3} \\
0_{1 \times 3}  & 0_{1 \times 3} & \pmb{\beta}_{1 \times 3} & 0_{1 \times 3} \\
0_{1 \times 3}  & 0_{1 \times 3} & 0_{1 \times 3} & \pmb{\beta}_{1 \times 3} \\
\end{bmatrix}_{4 \times 12}
\end{equation}

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! If the object has constant acceleration, why does the acceleration ($\ddot{x}, \ddot{y}, \ddot{z}$) need to be in the state? It can be, I'm just wondering whether it needs to be.

Comment: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/balzer82/Kalman/blob/master/Kalman-Filter-CA-2.ipynb?create=1

Comment: Ok, following that as an example, then your state looks good.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I'm still wondering about your question. In constant acceleration model, the acceleration need to be in the state or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [your link](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/balzer82/Kalman/blob/master/Kalman-Filter-CA-2.ipynb?create=1) in more detail, it says:

> Acceleration ($\ddot{x}$ & $\ddot{y}$) as well as position ($x$ & $y$) is measured.

which, to me, is not a **constant acceleration**.  What it is doing is a **discretized** changing acceleration model, assuming that the acceleration is constant between each sample period.

Now to your question: is inclusion of $\phi, \dot \phi,$ and $\ddot \phi$ in the state vector valid?

The answer is yes, but you need to include the dynamics of how those states interact with the other states.

---

OK, so now you've added the extra information, I can take a stab at it.

It should work with the following provisos:

- The noise distribution on the angle $\phi$ will be **uniform** not Gaussian.  I can't find a good reference, [but this discussion on `comp.dsp` mentions it](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/68256-1.php).  That means the KF equations for $\phi$ won't be quite right.  I don't think this is a big deal.
- There will be some coloration between the noise on $\phi$ and the noises on $x$ and $y$.  I'm not sure what this should be, but it may mean you need to introduce some off-diagonal terms in the $Q$ matrix in the KF formulation.

Comment: Please see $A$ and $H$ above.

Comment: question updated!